# Undefined name 'navigator' in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-layout

I have a StatefulWidget for page in flutter. On the press of a button I call the following method:

```
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
        iconSize: 25.0,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CallPage(title:contact)),
          );
        },
      ),
```

CallPage is another statefulWidget from which I am trying to create local and remote RTCVideoRenderers.

I use the following code to get the userMedia: video and audio from the navigator.

```
_getUserMedia() async {
final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
  'audio': false,
  'video': {'facingMode': 'user'}
};

if(await Permission.camera.request().isGranted) {
  if(await Permission.microphone.request().isGranted){
    MediaStream _localStream = await navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
    _localRenderer.srcObject = _localStream;
    return _localStream;
  }
}
```

}

Here, the Dart Analysis is throwing an error:

> error: Undefined name 'navigator'. (undefined_identifier at [chatapp] lib/home/call_page.dart:99)

I am going crazy now! This exact app was working a few minutes ago. Suddenly it stopped working.

I have tried deleting the build directory, running flutter clean, restarting the project, everything!!

Please HELP!

Comment: what is line 99?

Comment: where is the code for navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)?

Comment: getUserMedia is the function which returns the streaming object. mediaConstraints is a Map:final Map<String, dynamic> mediaConstraints = {
      'audio': false,
      'video': {'facingMode': 'user'}
    };

Comment: line 99 is the line where I'm calling navigator.getUserMedia

Comment: I guess we have the same question as your compiler... what **is** `navigator`? You have not given us *any* hint that we or your compiler should know what `navigator` is...

Comment: Isn't navigator present in a state of a stateful widget? Even in the official flutter-webrtc demo, they use navigator without defining it explicitly anywhere. https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo/blob/bde7e64e1ddf6721b3662bc9d6c0b6dd045b7ed3/lib/src/basic_sample/loopback_sample.dart

Comment: So the previous comment was wrong. I believed that navigator was like the javascript navigator. It is not so! It was a flutter-webrtc class. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name navigator has changed to MediaDevices in the flutter-webrtc package just on the day before this question was asked! Hope it helps someone.